# Linking statically GLEW with CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, glew

I know this subject is quite well documented and I tried looking for an awnser but I couldn't find any for my case.

I'm trying to link statically the windows libraries of GLEW and I get different mistakes depending what I do.

First here is my CMAKE file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Physics_Engine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

#target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE GLEW_STATIC)


find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)


add_subdirectory(lib/GLFW)

include_directories(lib/GLEW-WIN-LIB/include)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC lib/GLEW-WIN-LIB/lib/Release/x64)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opengl32 glfw glew32s)
```

And then my two kinds of problems :

#### 1/

If I keep the make file as is, I get this error :

```
[1/1] Linking CXX executable Physics_Engine.exe
FAILED: Physics_Engine.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\JetBrains\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/Physics_Engine.dir/src/main.cpp.obj -o Physics_Engine.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libPhysics_Engine.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/Users/matts/Documents/Projects/physics-engine-cpp/lib/GLEW-WIN-LIB/lib/Release/x64 -lopengl32  lib/GLFW/src/libglfw3.a  -lglew32s  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."


D:\JetBrains\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/Physics_Engine.dir/src/main.cpp.obj:C:/Users/matts/Documents/Projects/physics-engine-cpp/src/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `__imp_glewInit'
```

#### 2/

If I add the compile definitions :

```
[2/2] Linking CXX executable Physics_Engine.exe
FAILED: Physics_Engine.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\JetBrains\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/Physics_Engine.dir/src/main.cpp.obj -o Physics_Engine.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libPhysics_Engine.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/Users/matts/Documents/Projects/physics-engine-cpp/lib/GLEW-WIN-LIB/lib/Release/x64 -lopengl32  lib/GLFW/src/libglfw3.a  -lglew32s  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."


Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
D:\JetBrains\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/matts/Documents/Projects/physics-engine-cpp/lib/GLEW-WIN-LIB/lib/Release/x64/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0xd): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'
```

With 10 other lines like the last one

I tried using the `target_compile_definitions`; the `compile_definitions` and the `add_definitions` functions one at a time without it working...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of mingw / gcc?

Comment: First error can be explained by a mismatch, second error is because the linker does not know that glew32s requires symbols from opengl32. If you search for `__imp_wglGetProcAddress` you will end up on a nice MSDN page that tells you what to link.

Comment: You can be sure something is wrong if you consume a dependency by doing anything besides `find_package` followed by `target_link_libraries` to an imported (`::`) target (e.g. `OpenGL::GL`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second error can be solved by moving `glew32s` to the front of the linker inputs. The linker only resolves unresolved symbols from libraries that came earlier in the linker list.
Change your final line to:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glew32s opengl32 glfw)
```

Alternatively, you could use the nice [built-in CMake build support for GLEW](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLEW.html):

```
set(GLEW_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw GLEW::GLEW)
```

Note that you may have to give CMake some hints in the form of CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. See the documentation of the built-in `find_path` function.